# Python city shapefiles

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I recently came across a great set of free GIS data including all of the cities in the conus.  The shapefile contains several layers of information like the names, population, exct.  Ive plotted the location of the cities using basemaps built in shapefile reader.  However I cannot seem to find a way to plot the names of the cities along with the locations.  Is there a way to use basemap to plot the city names along with their locations?  Im using enthoughts canopy distribution since I am a student so certain addon modules might not be obtainable.  I have linked a sample of my output, and the link to the shapefile at the bottom of the post.  If anyone has any ideas that would be great!

Thanks, 
Andrew[image: sample output showing Western Oklahoma roads and cities]

Link to shapefile from Noaa National Weather service http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/national/html/cities.htm

Answer (score 0):

The following from the examples in the documentation should point you in the correct direction:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
# draw a boundary around the map, fill the background.
# this background will end up being the ocean color, since
# the continents will be drawn on top.
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
# fill continents, set lake color same as ocean color.
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
# label parallels on right and top
# meridians on bottom and left
parallels = np.arange(0.,81,10.)
# labels = [left,right,top,bottom]
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
meridians = np.arange(10.,351.,20.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])
# plot blue dot on Boulder, colorado and label it as such.
lon, lat = -104.237, 40.125 # Location of Boulder
# convert to map projection coords.
# Note that lon,lat can be scalars, lists or numpy arrays.
xpt,ypt = m(lon,lat)
# convert back to lat/lon
lonpt, latpt = m(xpt,ypt,inverse=True)
m.plot(xpt,ypt,'bo')  # plot a blue dot there
# put some text next to the dot, offset a little bit
# (the offset is in map projection coordinates)
plt.text(xpt+100000,ypt+100000,'Boulder (%5.1fW,%3.1fN)' % (lonpt,latpt))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Steve! I actually have used this method to plot thing before however, I am using shapefiles, and manually plotting the locations of the cities and their names isnt possible for me. Plotting the locations is the easy part and is already done im really only having trouble with the names.

Comment: Just extract the names, together with the lat/long, from the shapefile and plot it as above, see the pyshp documentation at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp#id6 for details on extracting the field data.